# memtester/mlock of huge allocation succeeds after running an app

Tags: embedded-linux

I am running BusyBox on embedded ArmV8 system with no swap memory.
When Linux loads, I apply 'free':

```
/ # free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        1009476       18396      989128           0        1952      957260
```

Then I run memtester 690M (which actually calls mlock) which fails:

```
pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffffffffffff000
want 690MB (723517440 bytes)
got  690MB (723517440 bytes), trying mlock ...[  106.591843] memtester invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14040c0(GFP_KERNEL|__GFP_COMP), nodemask=(null),  order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[  106.603174] memtester cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[  106.607474] CPU: 1 PID: 1392 Comm: memtester Tainted: G           O    4.14.76-19.0.0 #1
[  106.620744] Call trace:
[  106.623161] [<ffff0000080892a8>] dump_backtrace+0x0/0x358
[  106.628475] [<ffff000008089614>] show_stack+0x14/0x20
[  106.633448] [<ffff000008b35a10>] dump_stack+0x90/0xb0
[  106.638421] [<ffff000008192e14>] dump_header+0x90/0x1e8
[  106.643562] [<ffff000008191f90>] oom_kill_process+0xd0/0x518
[  106.649130] [<ffff000008192a00>] out_of_memory+0x180/0x490
[  106.654529] [<ffff000008197ff4>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0xadc/0xb60
[  106.660700] [<ffff0000081e6fd8>] alloc_pages_current+0x80/0xf0
[  106.666440] [<ffff0000081efb0c>] new_slab+0x40c/0x4e8
[  106.671410] [<ffff0000081f1a9c>] ___slab_alloc+0x474/0x548
[  106.676809] [<ffff0000081f1b94>] __slab_alloc.isra.22+0x24/0x38
[  106.682634] [<ffff0000081f2318>] kmem_cache_alloc+0x188/0x1c0
[  106.688291] [<ffff000008305614>] nfs_readhdr_alloc+0x1c/0x30
[  106.693861] [<ffff000008304400>] nfs_generic_pg_pgios+0x20/0xc0
[  106.699685] [<ffff000008303db4>] nfs_pageio_doio+0x34/0x80
[  106.705083] [<ffff000008304770>] __nfs_pageio_add_request+0xb0/0x370
[  106.711335] [<ffff0000083050c4>] nfs_pageio_add_request+0x14c/0x330
[  106.717502] [<ffff00000830595c>] readpage_async_filler+0x1c4/0x210
[  106.723585] [<ffff00000819d5c4>] read_cache_pages+0xb4/0x1a0
[  106.729153] [<ffff000008306394>] nfs_readpages+0xcc/0x1c0
[  106.734466] [<ffff00000819d80c>] __do_page_cache_readahead+0x15c/0x230
[  106.740892] [<ffff00000818fd58>] filemap_fault+0x308/0x5a0
[  106.746292] [<ffff0000081bf2f0>] __do_fault+0x20/0x70
[  106.751263] [<ffff0000081c4970>] __handle_mm_fault+0xa78/0x1010
[  106.757089] [<ffff0000081c5038>] handle_mm_fault+0x130/0x1d0
[  106.762660] [<ffff0000080a0c6c>] do_page_fault+0x134/0x3e8
[  106.768058] [<ffff0000080a0f68>] do_translation_fault+0x48/0x50
[  106.773883] [<ffff000008080ae4>] do_mem_abort+0x3c/0x98
[  106.779024] [<ffff000008080bd4>] do_el0_ia_bp_hardening+0x44/0xa0
```

Later I run some application and kills it.
If I run 'free' again, I get the same results as before, but this time calling memtster with 1G(!) succeeds for 930M.

```
/ # memtester 1G 1
memtester version 4.3.0 (64-bit)
Copyright (C) 2001-2012 Charles Cazabon.
Licensed under the GNU General Public License version 2 (only).

pagesize is 4096
pagesizemask is 0xfffffffffffff000
want 1024MB (1073741824 bytes)
got  934MB (979906560 bytes), trying mlock ...locked.
```

Why memtester of 690M failed the first time?
How can I enable it to succeed without running the application?

Comment: Is OOM killer invoked also even if you wait for example 3 minutes after boot (or whatever time it takes to finish init 100%), before first executing memtester?